# custom views in taxonomy tags pages

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have created a custom view for my Drupal 7 front page, and I have named it "Recent Products", but this view is only working for the front page is not working in taxonomies, tags, content preview pages.

How do I apply this view for every page, or set it as default for pages?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish, and what problems you're encountering. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: See [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38422/editing-default-views-of-a-theme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding: The Views module is used to create pages, or blocks. In both the cases, the created view shows nodes, users, taxonomy terms, modules, etc matching some criteria set for the view.

A view is not a template for altering the content of other pages. For that there is the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module. (Emphasis is mine.)

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content manager that lets you **visually design a layout and place content within that layout**. Integration with other systems allows you to create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this, and even **override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page** so that you can **customize the layout of your site** with very fine grained permissions.

Comment: thanks, but i can't understand why custom "Views" will not work for Category Pages etc.

Comment: I cannot tell you that without seeing the view. Also, what you mean by "category pages"?

Comment: oh sorry it means Taxonomy Pages

Comment: It depends from the view's settings. For example, if the view shows a list of users, it cannot be used for showing taxonomy terms; other settings can change how the view works, and can determine if the view is working as expected. Anyway, your question is "How do I apply this view for every page?" for which the answer is "You don't apply views to pages."

Comment: thanks,, is that machine name .... or what to do to apply views to pages so that the Views will not work for the Home page only, it will work for the Taxonomy pages also..

Comment: It is just the settings. For example, if you are filtering the posts to the ones promoted to front page, then that view is better used for the front page; if you are using the same view for taxonomy terms, then the first thing you should do is removing the filter for posts promoted to front page. The list of settings that should be changed to make a view work for a different case is too long; at the worse, that list includes all the settings available for a view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4313/discussion-between-rakibtg-and-kiamlaluno)